# how can i convert this code to the java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I wanted to convert this for looping to a stream line

```java
List<String> newLore = new ArrayList<>();
for (String str : description) {
    newLore.add(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', str));
}
itemMeta.setLore(newLore);
```

Comment: What is `description`?

Comment: Weak title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue

Comment: "needs details or clarity"? How is THIS unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following chain of methods. The key is to `map` each of the items to a new one and finally collect to a `List`.

```
List<String> newLore = description.stream()                       // Stream<String> with old elements
    .map(str -> ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', str)) // Stream<String> with the new ones
    .collect(Collectors.toList());                                // List<String>
itemMeta.setLore(newLore);
```